# Proper implementation of the Laravel bundle from Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How to use Laravel with Vue. I know how to make an API on Laravel and on the front to output data using Vue. Here's how to make partial use of Vue. For example, a project similar to Booking.com. On the main page, everything is static except for the Ajax input "Where to go". Is it possible to implement this input as a Vue component and place it in a blade template? Also tell me how you would implement it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with both Laravel and Vue and want to have one monorepo for your project, you can try inertiaJs: https://inertiajs.com

Personally, I would split the project and put the API backend in one repo and the VueJS frontend into another repo. In my opinion this should make your code cleaner and you will not be tightened with some limitations of inertia.